# Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.2.5.RELEASE:run (default-cli)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

I am new to spring boot and am trying to run a application which runs with maven spring-boot:run.
I downloaded a spring application from spring initializr and am trying to run that in IntelliJ IDE community edition 2019.3.3 but was getting the following error:

> Failed to execute goal
>   org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.2.5.RELEASE:run
>   (default-cli) on project demo: Application finished with exit code: 1

My code is:

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

My pom.xml file is:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema- 
instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
        <!--  lookup parent from repository  -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.revanth</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I later changed to NetBeans IDE and tried to run the application but got the same error.
The full stack of errors are:

Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.2.5.RELEASE:run (default-cli) on project demo: Application finished with exit code: 1 -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.2.5.RELEASE:run (default-cli) on project demo: Application finished with exit code: 1

```
at
```

org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:217)

```
at
```

org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)

```
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by:
org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Application finished with exit code: 1
at org.springframework.boot.maven.RunMojo.runWithForkedJvm(RunMojo.java:108)
at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo.doRunWithForkedJvm(AbstractRunMojo.java:292)
at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo.run(AbstractRunMojo.java:257)
at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo.execute(AbstractRunMojo.java:213)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
... 19 more
```

Comment: Have you tried to build the application first?

Comment: Indeed, like M.Ismail says you might need to make Maven build the application at least once in order to get and compile the dependencies. I don't remember if IntelliJ does this automatically; it might do it for you, but that requires that the project is correctly configured with Maven inside IntelliJ.
Do you have any more error logs or stack traces that could help us identify the problem?

Comment: Yes, I built the application and tried again, but the problem still persists.

Comment: Did you find a solution ?

Comment: Sorry for the very late response, I tried building the application in STS. It is working well in that.

Answer (score 2):

The above error is basically come due to plugin issue in maven for spring-boot

You can run the project in different way also if you want to run

First create a jar for the project by running

> mvn clean install

Then run the jar from normal java command

> java -jar **jar-localtion**.jar

if want to run with any specific profile then use this

> java -Dspring.profiles.active= -jar **jar-localtion**.jar

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue and solved it by simply clicking mouse right button hovering over "spring-boot-maven-plugin" in pom.xml (which was red warning colour), select 'Maven' and then select 'Download sources'

It took a few seconds to download sources and the red/ warning is gone.